# How to include multiple html file in another phtml file?

Tags: php, magento, include, magento2

I would like to include several file in Magento 2 in one phtml file.
The project was in laravel at first and looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpA7z.png

So now I need to import all the project in a Magento 2 project but the semantic is different.
I have tried this so far but doesnt work :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5tUd.png

The files I'm trying to call are in a subfolder and the path of these files is :

> Wo/EyeTest/view/frontend/templates/eyetestSteps

with other subfolders like

> Wo/EyeTest/view/frontend/templates/eyetestSteps/step1/

> Wo/EyeTest/view/frontend/templates/eyetestSteps/step2/

Do you have any idea how can I do this ? When the file is in the same directory, there is no problem, it's display, and I guess I'm writting the path badly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below path for this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Wo_EyeTest::eyetestSteps/step1/_instructions.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```